# When multiplying an integer getting back a matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement

I have extracted a speed sign from an image. [image]

Then, I used ocr in matlab to check what number is in the bottom right image. Answer was 20. I then added this to an array. When array is `disp(array)` it shows 20 as it should. 
But I couldnt check for `ismember`, so I started to `disp` other options. When I try to `disp(A*2)` I get not 40, but an array with random numbers `100   158    20    20`. Why is that? How can I just check if the answer I originaly got from `number=results.Text` is 20 or not with an if statement?
my code:

```
I = imread('p7.tif');
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(I);title('Original Image'); 
%sharpen edges
B = imsharpen(I);
subplot(2,2,2);imshow(B);title('sharpened edges');

%find circles
Img = im2bw(B(:,:,3));
minRad = 20;
maxRad = 90;
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(Img, [minRad maxRad], ...
                                    'ObjectPolarity','bright','sensitivity',0.87);
imagesc(Img);
viscircles(centers, radii,'Color','green');

rect = [centers(1)-(radii - radii/3.5),centers(2)-(radii - radii/3.5),2*(radii-radii/3.5),2*(radii-radii/3.5)];
I2 = imcrop(I,rect);

subplot(2,2,3);imshow(I2);title('crop');
%to gray
gray = rgb2gray(I2);
Icorrected = imtophat(gray, strel('disk', 15));
black = im2bw(gray);
results = ocr(black);
number = results.Text;

A = number;
array = [];
array = [array,A];
disp(array)
%result is 20


disp(A)
%result is 20

disp(A*2)
%results is 100   158    20    20

subplot(2,2,4);imshow(black);title('crop');
```

EDIT:
Since A is a string i tried to do this:

```
A = number;
B = '20';
tf = strcmp(A,B)
```

But tf = 0
how can I check that A is 20 or not?

Comment: `results.Text` is not a numeric array, so `disp(A)` is showing you `'20  '`, not `20`. Multiplying character arrays by an integer will return the ASCII equivalent. Try `disp('hi'*2)`.

Comment: Can I check if A is number 20 somehow? Or it contains number 2 in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation for [`ocr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocr.html), the return is an [`ocrText` object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocrtext-class.html) whose `Text` property is:

> Text recognized by OCR, specified as an array of characters. The text includes white space and new line characters.

Multiplying a character array by a numeric array will convert the character array into a numeric one (generally the ASCII equivalent) before multiplying. You can see this with:

```
>> disp('hi'*2)
   208   210
```

In your case, you have `'2O  '` rather than `20`, which can be seen with your "random" array:

```
>> disp(char([100 158 20 20]/2))
2O
```

Notice that you've matched `O` and not `0`, so the simple `str2double` will not work in this case. There are a couple options around this:

If you know that you are only looking for digits, you can specify a [`'CharacterSet'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocr.html#namevaluepairarguments) to `ocr` so it will not match letters:

```
results = ocr(black, 'CharacterSet', '0123456789');
number = str2double(results.Text);
```

Otherwise you can build a substitution dictionary to swap characters for their "equivalents." The MATLAB toolbox may have built-in functionality for this, but I'm not familiar enough with the toolbox to know off-hand.

Answer (score 0):

in your code `A` is actually a char array `'20'` and not a scalar `20`.

when you do `disp(A)` it displays the chars `'20'`, but when you do `disp(A*2)` it first convert `A` elements (`['2','0']`) into double (`[50 48]`) and then multiply by 2:

```
A = '20';
disp(A) % 20
disp(class(A)) % char
A2 = A*2;
disp(class(A2)) % double
disp(A*2) % 100 96
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining, makes sense now! Is there a way I can check if A is/contains 20? Thats what the goal is for me, to get 'YES' or 'NO' if answer matches the sign number.

Comment: str2double(A) == 20 or strcmp(A,'20')